# Network booted RPi3 can't find 1wire devices

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, 1wire

Currently trying to implement a net-booted RPi3b+ network and there is an auxiliary board to these pi's I've had printed. The auxiliary board has a classic DS18B20 among other things to monitor the temperature of the box the rpi and aux board are contained in.

The issue is, when I use a netbooted pi I cannot get any devices to show up (including the w1_bus_master1) when I access /sys/bus/w1/devices. See below,

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ cd /sys/bus/w1/devices/
pi@raspberrypi:/sys/bus/w1/devices $ ls -l
total 0
```

I know that my circuit is correct as it works when I boot the RPi from an SD card with the same image of raspbian as the netbooted image. On the netbooted rpi I see the 1-wire processes running for w1-therm and w1-gpio.

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
w1_therm               16384  0
w1_gpio                16384  0
wire                   40960  2 w1_gpio,w1_therm
```

My netbooting process roughly follows this tutorial,
https://blockdev.io/network-booting-a-raspberry-pi-3/

I have a NFS mount which holds the config.txt file containing the
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4

I'm pulling my hair out a bit here, really would like to maintain the netbooting capability as this implementation is preferred to last and is across 30+ pi's, don't want to be pissing about the sd cards.

Cheers